bun run time. Call the library that you wrote, run the display Cannot find package
enter image description here
bun run time. Call the library that you wrote, run the display Cannot find package.Is it a dependency library problem
library tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Enable latest features
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@lib/*": [
        "lib/*"
      ]
    },
    "outDir": "./bmc",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    // Bundler mode
//    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    // 启用导入 .ts 扩展
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    // 只生成声明文件
    "emitDeclarationOnly": false,
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    // Best practices
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    // Some stricter flags (disabled by default)
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["./lib/**/*"]
}

